# How to use CombineLatest in Angular Guard with Ngrx

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to wait for several slice of state to be `true` in my guard.

I tried like so :

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return combineLatest([
      this.store.select(
        fromStore.selectProductsLoaded
      ),
      this.store.select(fromStore.selectArticlesLoaded),
    ]).pipe(
      map(([a, b]) => ({ a, b })),
      filter(({ a, b}) =>  a && b),
      first()
    );
  }
```

I need these two data to be `true` so I thought of using `combineLatest` but ran into this error :
`Type 'Observable<{ a: boolean; b: boolean; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'`

In comparaison, this works :

```
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return  this.store
      .select(fromStore.selectProductsLoaded)
      .pipe(
        filter((loaded) => loaded),
        take(1)
      );
  }
```

Comment: `filter` doesn't transform the result type, if you want a boolean result did you mean `map(([a, b]) => a && b)`? Or do you only want to emit when it will be true, in which case the value seems a bit pointless.

Comment: Aaah you're right! it works now, if you want to post that as an answer so I can set this as the right answer :)

Comment: Great, I'd suggest just deleting the question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you end up using `combineLatest` for data coming from your store, IMO you can think of this as a red flag or a code smell.

If you want to combine some data coming out of your store, use a selector. The main difference being that the observable will only need to be fired once instead of at least twice for the `combineLatest` (which will wait for both to emit).

It could look like the following:

```
const canActivateNameOfYourRoute = createSelector(
  fromStore.selectProductsLoaded,
  fromStore.selectArticlesLoaded,
  (productsLoaded, articlesLoaded) => productsLoaded && articlesLoaded
);

class YourGuard {
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.store.select(canActivateNameOfYourRoute).pipe(
      filter(Boolean),
      first()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't think of this solution which seems obviously better. Did you write the new selector on the same file just for the example or do you consider it as a best practice versus a proper selectors file?

Comment: Really depends on the usage. In general, having 1 file with all your selectors is a good idea as each selector will hold a cached value to avoid recomputing if the inputs didn't change. But, if you're definitely not going to reuse that selector elsewhere it may be a good idea to leave it around the code which is using it. So unfortunately not a black and white answer, you'll have to do what's best based on your own judgement :)

Answer (score 1):

The point why you get this error is because with combineLatest you pass an array of observables and then mapping it to an object of the structure {a: boolean, b: boolean}.

I guess you want to return ONE boolean based on those two inputs.

So a possible solution could be

```
.pipe(
      map(([a, b]) => ({ a, b })),
      filter(({ a, b}) =>  a && b),
      map(values => {
        // both a and b are true
        if(values.a && values.b){
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }),
      first()
    );
```